# How to launch AWS instance so that it works when I turn off my computer?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am new at AWS. I have created instance with the help of youtube guides, run putty, install node to my remote server and my website works correct. But when I turn off putty console, the site stops working. Should I run some code in my console or what? In AWS instance has status: running... I want to turn off my computer and leave the site running. Server works with ubuntu and node.js in it.

P.S: I am working with EC2